# Как правильно сверстать

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

https://prnt.sc/qjqpqp
Когда верстаю задний фон текст проваливается под фон. Я планировал сделать два блока и с помощью position: absolute; расставить их по краям с лева и права.

```css
#services{
background: #2F343A;
padding - bottom: 100px;
position: relative;
}

.service - rectangle__first{
  background: #393F47;
  height: 100px;
  width: 755px;
  height: 561px;
  position: absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 0;
}

.services - line__wrapper{
  padding - top: 120px;
  padding - bottom: 46px;
}

.services - line{
  width: 90px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #C8A35F;
}

.services - title{
 color: #fff;
 font - size: 40px;
 text - transform: uppercase;
 letter - spacing: 2px;
 width: 300px;
 margin : 0;
 padding - bottom: 25px;
}

.services - subtitle{
  padding - bottom: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 320px;
  font - size: 18px;
}

.service - btn{
  width: 220px;
  height: 55px;
  text - transform: uppercase;
  letter - spacing: 1px;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s;
  font - size: 12px;
  color: #2F343A;
}

.service - btn:hover{
  background: #C8A35F;
  color: #fff;
}

.services - background__left{
   left : 0;
   top : 0;
   position: absolute;
   background: #393F47;
   width: 755px;
   height: 560px;
}
```

```html
<section id = "services">
 <div class = "container">
  <div class = "services-background__left">< / div>
  <div class = "services-line__wrapper">
   <div class = "services-line">< / div>
  </div>
  <h2 class = "services-title">грузоперевозки по европе< / h2>
  <div class = "services-subtitle">Страны Евросоюза, а также Белоруссия со всеми документами.</div>
  <button class = "service-btn"><h3>Подробнее<h3>< / button>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Для послойного отображения элементов используйте свойство z-index, чем выше значение z-index тем выше находится элемент. Z-index может применяться к элементам которым задано значение position: relative, absolute, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать [background: linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #393e46 40%, #2f343a 40% 60%, #393e46 60% 100%);
```